# Create and manage Google Form through NodeJS app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, google-apps-script, google-forms

My use-case is the following:
Desktop app using Electron and React; The user may create a Google Form *through the app*, possibly through my own crafted interface, or displaying the webview inside the app, with limited controls (I would like to avoid having to open a web page if possible). Said form is then sent by email to contacts, and the app periodically checks for new submissions to display them in the dashboard.

However Google Form is rather convoluted on this point. For starters there doesn't seem to be an API for this unless you go through AppScript, and as of now I'm very unclear about what I can and cannot do with it.

What I'm looking for mostly is pointers; The online form doesn't necessarily need to be Google's, as I'm rather put off by the lack of a proper JS API. It does need to come without limitations however, as this is 
meant as a free app.

Any and all suggestions are welcome.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

GAS is likely going to be the best way to go, but it's hard to know exactly what you want to do without seeing what you've already tried. But as far as I can tell, [this documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/) is pretty extensive.

Another simple route would be to link the form setup inside an iframe if you are opposed to going to a separate web page. You can then track the submissions on the google sheet, in which there is a lot of documentation on the sheets' API.

The other option is creating your own form if you don't want to deal with a third party's API, but in the end you're still going to need to read through docs and figure out what suits your need best. And that's primarily an opinion-based answer.